# Prove or disprove: If graph $G$ has at most $3n-1$ edges, then $\chi(G) \leq 6$

Tags: graph-theory

The question is to prove or disprove that if graph $G$ has at most $3n-1$ edges, then the chromatic number is at most $6$. I tried to work it out using the fact that $\chi(G) \leq \triangle(G) + 1$, but I can't think of a relation between the max degree and the number of edges.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This seems impossible: for every fixed $k$, consider the complete graph on $k$ vertices and append to it a long linear portion, then, if the number of vertices is $n$, when $n\to\infty$, the number of edges is $n+O(1)$ and the chromatic number is (at least) $k$. For your homework, take $k=7$.

Comment: But maybe $n$ is not the number of vertices of $G$... What is $n$?

Comment: n is the number of vertices of G. I don't get what you meant that the number of edges increases by 1 when n goes to infinity. Thanks for your help

Comment: Or what did you mean by n+O(1)

Comment: O(1) means constant number of edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so, consider $K_7$, It has $21$ edges which $3*7$. But then add a path of length $2$ to it to get the graph $G$ like in the following picture:
[image]

Then $\chi(G)=7$, $n=9$and  $E(G)=23 <3*n-1=26$. So dosent't work!

Comment: Thanks! I get it now